# jQuery trigger click vs click ()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have this simple code :  **[here](http://jsbin.com/ajepiv/edit#source)**

```
$(".btn").on('click',function () {

  $(".a").trigger('click');
});

$(".btn2").on('click',function () {

  $(".a")[0].click();
});
```

I'm trying to simulate pressing on Anchor.

But when I use jQuery's `trigger`, it doesn't work (why?)

When I use `"jsobj".click()` func, it does work.

After reading the jQuery documentation, I don't see any reason why it shouldn't.

Help ?

PS: I'm using Chrome.

Comment: Did you try $(".a")[0].trigger('click') ?

Comment: this will work , the question is why trigger('click') doesnt work

Comment: Very interesting observation indeed..

Comment: You'll find a clearer answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505003/jquery-calling-triggerclick-vs-click

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually `$(".a").trigger('click');` triggers the click event but it doesn't mean that it'll click the link, instead it'll execute the event handler if you already have one, i.e.

```
$(".btn, .btn2").on('click',function () {
    $($(".a")[0]).trigger('click'); // first element
});

$(".a").on('click', function (e){
    alert(e.target);
});​
```

The given example will trigger the click event of the `a` and will execute the handler (the anonymous function) that's already have been registered for that event using

```
$(".a").on('click', function (e){...});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/Lrw9A/)

Comment: so whtqa is the difference between click and trigger click ?

Comment: you should have a `handler` defined to trigger a `click event` then both way you can trigger the event, i.e. `$(".a").trigger('click');` or `$($(".a")[0]).click();` but you have to have a `click handler for that.`

Comment: sorry, i dont understand why trigger click on  button will actually do as if i pressed it , while trigger href wont

Comment: this is different scenario.here you attached explictly the on click to the href.

Answer (score 3):

because `$(".a")[0]` return raw JavaScript node you cannot use jQuery object methods for that.

Comment: but if i bind to it a click event , and then use trigger, it will work... so...?

Answer (score 2):

This is because JQuery's `.trigger()` doesn't really trigger the native events. Try this for example in your script:

```
$(".btn").on('click',function () {

  $(".a").trigger('click');
});
$(".a").click(function(){alert('triggered!')});
```

When you create a costume handler using JQuery, THEN the event will be triggered with the `.trigger()` method.

**Update:** This is quite interesting, seems to happen only with `<a>` tags AND with `href`. [Check this out](http://jsbin.com/ejoduw/edit)

Comment: where it says that trigger doesnt  trigger the native events ( altoght i know its the answer by behavior )

Comment: @RoyiNamir, Check the example in the update, very interesting. As for where it says, I've just concluded that.